# Custom Cell is displayed incorrectly in TableView

Tags: ios, interface, swift

i am trying to add a custom cell to a master-detail application. I created my custom cell by creating a xib with the interface builder. The application loads and I can add items using the "add button". However the cell is not displayed correctly and I have no idea where the problem might be.

Thanks for any input!

Master View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var objects = NSMutableArray()


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var nipName=UINib(nibName: "FeedTableCell", bundle:nil)
        self.tableView.registerNib(nipName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "insertNewObject:")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    }

    func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
        if objects == nil {
            objects = NSMutableArray()
        }
        objects.insertObject(NSDate.date(), atIndex: 0)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FeedTableCell

        cell.loadItem(user:"user1", hoop: "#Yolo", post: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magn")

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            objects.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }
}
```

Class associated with the custom cell:

```
    import UIKit

class FeedTableCell : UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet var userLabel: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var hoopLabel: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var postLabel: UILabel

    func loadItem(#user: String, hoop: String, post: String) {
        userLabel.text = user
        hoopLabel.text = hoop
        postLabel.text = post
    }

}
```

The custom cell in the interface builder
[image: Custom cell]

What it looks like when "add" is pressed the first time
[image: + klicked first time]

What it looks like when "add" is pressed multiple times
[image: + klicked 3 times]

Comment: the problem is related with height of cells., you need to increase it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is a bunch of cells all with height 0 and the cell separators all pressed up against each other - this creates the gray view. In iOS8 cell heights are calculated automatically for you based on your auto-layout constraints.

Make sure your all your subviews are pinned to the edges of the content view so the cell knows how high it is supposed to be.

An example is here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout